# How does Level come to play with Fetishes?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse, translations, werewolf-20th-anniversary

I do not manage to understand how Level affects Fetishes. The rules (at least those which I have, W20 translated into Spanish) talk about Gnosis several times, but I do not find anything about Level, except in the Fetishes descriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Level" is a ranking of the power of a fetish. It comes into play when you allot your Background dots in Fetish; your rank in dots says how many combined Levels of fetishes you can start with. Three dots in Fetish will get you three Level Ones, a Level Three, or any other combination that adds to 3.

So Level does not affect gameplay, just character creation. It's a means of measuring power in a simple way.

Comment: I also use the fetish's level to determine whether a garou can make the fetish themselves – garou need dots in craft and rituals skills at least equal to the fetish's level to make it – or whether to make the fetish available to a PC or NPC – I wouldn't allow rank 1 garou to access a level 5 fetish, unless it was done by the Fetish background.